# Is there any way to reference all of the objects instantiated from a JavaScript Class?

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, children

This is not a browser or DOM specific question.  If a number of child objects are instantiated from a JavaScript class, is there an easy way to iterate through those objects?  I know there might be some way to do this through the Object prototype chain, but I am not sure how to do this or how to do it efficiently.  Would this be different in Node versus a browser window?

Comment: No, nothing automatically keeps track of all the objects in a class. If you need such a list, have the contructor do it.

Comment: Why do you think you need this? Sounds like [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I recently worked using a game development language and IDE that had a way to do this easily for a game that would run for a long time and needed the dynamic creation and removal of large number of game objects based on events.  

It would be nice to be able to do this also within JavaScript efficiently for perhaps children and further descendants of a class.  Although this has been marked as previously answered, the answers seemed to provide trivial obvious solutions such as just storing the object references in an array in the class constructor or traversing all objects for matches.